# Can I destructure a React Context for use in useEffect without violating the rules of React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The crux of the question is: **How can I use data from context to trigger useEffect?**

As I understand the rules of hooks, they all have to be at the top of the function, so this is probably a violation, right?

```
export const MyComponent = () => {
    const appContext = useContext(AppContext);
    const {dispatch, state} = appContext;  // destructuring in front of another hook
    useEffect(()=>{
        // Do something with state here
    }, [state]);
}
```

The only other way that I can think of doing this without directly passing state as a prop is to use local component state, but this looks truly horrible to me.

```
export const MyComponent = () => {
    const appContext = useContext(AppContext);
    const [state, setState] = useState({});
    useEffect(()=>{
        const {_state} = appContext;
        setState(_state);
    },[]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        // Do something with state here
    }, [state]);

    const {dispatch} = appContext;
}
```

I appreciate all suggestions. Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a destructing statement in between two hooks is not a violation of the rules of hooks. What the Rules of hook state is that `Only Call Hooks at the Top Level` and not `Only Call Hooks at the Top of function`

The idea is that you don't have hooks within `loops, conditions, or nested functions`

What you need to take care of is that the the total number of hooks remain the same on each render of the component.

Hence below code is a perfectly valid and correct code

```
export const MyComponent = () => {
    const appContext = useContext(AppContext);
    const {dispatch, state} = appContext;  
    useEffect(()=>{
        // Do something with state here
    }, [state]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The code works, but I was afraid that I was introducing a random, impossible to debug future problem. I'll accept the answer in a few minutes when the platform allows me to.